# how to Include&bundle css file from bower components

Tags: bower, jhipster

I am adding to my jhipster project a new dependency "*tether-shepherd*", and below was my steps:

```
bower install tether-shepherd --save
```

the dependency was successfully installed & added to '*bower.json*', then to add it to '*index.html*' I ran below command

```
gulp inject
```

the js files was successfully added to index.html but without any .css theme files, when I dig into installed bower components for installed dependency I found all themes there in 'bower_components/tether-shepherd/dist/css/' directory but not included to index.html file, to add it I manually placed its include below loading-bar.css in   section but it is automatically removed when I re-run gulp inject!,  and when I add it manually outside any block this was not good for production profile

**any professional way to include and bundle css files located in bower_components?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because these CSS are not referenced in the `main` property of your dependencie's `bower.json` like [here](https://github.com/HubSpot/shepherd/blob/master/bower.json#L20), see `gulp/inject.js` in your project to understand how they are used.

So, either you add an `overrides.main` property for these dependencies in your JHipster app's `bower.json` to add them like [JHipster does for Bootstrap](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/bower.json#L52-L56) or you manage them manually and copy them to `src/main/webapp/content/css`, (you may have to add `@import` to your `main.css` I didn't test).

Comment: thanks Gaël for your help, resolved by adding overrides.main property in project's bower.json file to include theme css file.